# C# Load TextBlock content from a valriable (containing images)

Tags: c#, wpf

I just wrote some nice functions, that allow me to add Emojis in a textbox with Inline.Add([Syste.Windows.Controls.Image]). It basically takes a TextBlock as an argument and appends the text/emojis that I want.

Icons is a Dictionary which maps from string to BitmapImage. (unable to use '<' and '>' here somehow)

```
   private void AddTextToString(TextBlock block, string txt)
   {
       var textRun = new Run(txt);
       textRun.BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Center;
       block.Inlines.Add(textRun);
   }

   private void AddEmojiToString(TextBlock block, string txt)
   {
       if (!Icons.ContainsKey(txt))
           return;

       System.Windows.Controls.Image emo = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
       emo.Height = 15;            
       emo.Width = 15;
       emo.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
       emo.Source = Icons[txt];
       block.Inlines.Add(emo);
   }
```

Now I was wondering if there was an elegant way of saving this kind of text to a variable, so that I could bind the TextBlock Text dynamically to it.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I think, need tiny programming language and interpreter for saving this functionality to a string. XML is will be a good base language. If you just want to make API clearly, design a `Builder` class. It is much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextBlock.Inlines` is property of type [InlineCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inlinecollection(v=vs.110).aspx), you can use this type to keep the contents.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!
may be a dumb question.. I am not very used to WPF, but
Do i then declare a System.Windows.Documents.InlineCollection Element
and simply add lines to that one ?
or could you maybe make a small example ?